# Compact Support on Differential Form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, complex-geometry

The following question references [Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces](http://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/Foster.pdf). It is shown that if $g \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{C})$ is of compact support, then there is a solution $f \in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{C})$ of the equation $\partial f/\partial \bar{z} = g$ having compact support if and only if $$\int \int_{\mathbb{C}} z^n g(z)dz   \wedge d\bar{z} = 0 \tag 1$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here, $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{C})$ denotes the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra of functions differentiable with respect to the coordinates $x$ and $y$, for $z=x+iy.$ 
Let $\omega$ be a smooth one-form such that $\omega \in \Omega_c^{1}(X)$, where $\Omega_c^{1}(X)$ denotes the space of continuous one-forms with compact support. $X$ is a Riemann surface with boundary $\partial X$ consisting of piecewise smooth curves, for $\omega$ defined on a neighborhood of the closure of $X$.

> If $\omega(z)$ has compact support on $X$, then is there a condition similar to $(1)$ that can be imposed, such that there is a solution $\sigma \in \Omega_c^{1}(X)$ of the equation $\partial \sigma/\partial \bar{z} = \omega$ having compact support if and only if this condition is satisfied?

Proposition: Let $\pi$ be a conformal diffeomorphism $\pi:X \to U,$ then for $\sigma=g(z)dz$, $$\int \int_{\mathbb{C}} z^n g(z)dz   \wedge d\bar{z} =\int \int_{\pi^{-1}(\mathbb{C})=X} \pi^{*}(z^n \sigma   \wedge d\bar{z}) \equiv \int \int_{X} \pi^{*}(z^n \sigma)   \wedge \pi^{*}d\bar{z}.$$ It follows that if $\sigma \in \Omega_c^{1}(\mathbb{C})$ is of compact support, then there is a solution $\omega \in \Omega_c^{1}(\mathbb{C})$ of the equation $\partial \omega/ \partial \bar z=\sigma$ having compact support if and only if $$\int \int_{X} \pi^{*}(z^n \sigma)   \wedge \pi^{*}d\bar{z}=0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Huh? $X$ is compact. Every form has compact support.

Comment: I will remove the compactness condition. @MikeMiller

Comment: Could you please try to specify what you mean by "can be written in terms of"? For instance, if $\phi$ is a smooth, positive function with compact support in the open unit disk and $\omega = \phi\, dz$, what kind of $\sigma$ are you seeking?

Comment: How is $\omega$ defined on a neighborhood of the closure of $X$ if it's compactly supported in $X$?

Comment: Also, how about $\sigma=i\omega$?

Comment: I am referring to a condition that can be constructed between $\omega$ and $\sigma$ that yields these properties. By this, I mean something analogous (Generalized to differential forms) to Dolbeault's Lemma, or similar to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785194/solution-to-cauchy-riemann-differential-equation-of-compact-support).@AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: More specifically, I am looking for a differential form $\sigma$ that can be written as an integral expression of $\omega,$ which also satisfies these properties. @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: The question you linked refers to a _specific relationship_ between a smooth, complex-valued _function_ $g$ and a function $f$ with $\partial f/\partial\bar{z} = g$. **That** is the type of condition that would make your question comprehensible to me. As with your [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922191) (and a second asked several days ago that appears to have been deleted), I'm afraid I don't understand what you're getting at here. Best wishes all the same....